# SharePoint Admin and Developer Roles

Tags: web-part, deployment, solution-deployment

Currently in our organization we have a three man SharePoint development team where we do everything other than SharePoint admin.

Our organization has development, test, and production servers.

We, the development team, have the ability to deploy web parts to the dev server but not to test or production.

This has become quite a nuisance having to wait for the admin to get around to deploying our web parts to test and then to production.

**Does anyone else have a similar experience or is our organization setup wrong?**

**Do developers normally have access to deploy web parts to test and production?**

Comment: Guys, I'm not sure how this question can be reasonable answered. It depends on so many different factors: how large the org is, what teams there are, resources, your boss' feeling that day...

Comment: I agree. I'm not really sure it's the best fit for SE Q&A. Perhaps it should be moved to chat?

Comment: Agreed.  This is really a *discussion* rather than a question about definitive SharePoint usage.  I don't think this is the right place either.

Comment: This is where I think SE needs improvement. While this question may not fit in the narrow guidelines of what SE is looking for it is definitely not **not constructive**. While an alternative exists for *StackOverflow* for these types of questions, such as *Code Review*, these more specialty focused sites, sharepoint.stackexchange.com, do not. I think these specialty sites need to be a little more flexible in their guidelines and allow these constructive questions a little leeway especially considering the amount of traffic they receive. Can I get an up vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do developers normally have access? It depends on the company and it depends on the project. I've worked on projects where I deploy all the way up to production, and I've worked on projects where my involvement ends when an admin deploys to test.

Do developers want access? Naturally.

Do admins want developers to have access? Not typically.

Is your organization set up wrong? Ask your boss?

Admins are gate keepers, it's what they do. Is it annoying for developers? Yeah, but admins need to feel important somehow.

Is there a reason admins block developers from dropping code on their servers all willy-nilly? Yeah, because a lot of bad developers think they're good developers.

There's two sides to the coin.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this mentality: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seliot/archive/2011/04/25/i-don-t-always-test-my-code-but-when-i-do-i-do-it-in-production.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would say that developers normally have access to at least test. I am a SharePoint Consultant-Developer and at most of my clients we have some access to a test server. Of course it matters the importance of test and the size of the org. Our big clients it is hard to get on test, or we have to make new test servers for each project. At smaller clients usually there is some access. It sounds like they do not trust developer, which seems normal with SP devs as well. I would say find out the reason.

Is it the admins being paranoid or is test really that volatile?

I can see how it would slow you down and it would piss me off too.

Answer (score 3):

That's typical. Admins are normally responsible for keeping the servers and applications running up and available. If they aren't the ones deploying the solutions, you cut them out of the loop and they then have difficulty supporting their servers and applications.

They are the ones getting called initially when applications and servers aren't beahving normally. If they don't know what is being developed installed and deployed, it makes things more difficult for them.